# How can I run my app on Galaxy J7 emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, samsung-galaxy

I've created an android application, This app works correctly in all of the android phones but somebody has announced that my application didn't work from yesterday! his phone is `galaxy Samsung j7 prime`. I want to test the app on this device with an emulator. How can I create an emulator like `j7 prime`?

I searched for online emulators but none of them is not for `j7 prime`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Firebase` `testlab` and use `Robo script`,with device you wish.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Can you post a tutorial or link for how I doing this?

Comment: @Fahim
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/overview

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link, I have tried this way it's working fine for me. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3C5NU__Ut2U 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llIbIXsreQo